# Could not find where goes wrong

Tags: java, android

I am new to Java and Android and I want to make an Android program that lets the users to type in the tag price and click on the Get Final Price button and the program is able to show the final price. (after the tax which is 8%)
I can't post pictures because I just registered and have 0 reputation. So I copy my code below. There are no red lines but it just won't run. Please help me. I do appreciate everyone's answer. Thanks!!

code from TaxCalculator.java:

```
package com.finalproject.taxcalculator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TaxCalculator extends Activity
{
private EditText text;

private EditText tagPriceEditText;
private EditText totalPriceEditText;

private TextView tagPriceTextView;
private TextView totalPriceTextView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tagPriceEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tagPriceEditText);
    tagPriceEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.totalPriceEditText);

    tagPriceTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tagPriceTextView);
    totalPriceTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.totalPriceTextView);

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            //Perform action here
            //Ignore. Haven't done yet.
            double tagPrice = Double.parseDouble(tagPriceEditText.getText().toString());
            double totalPrice = tagPrice * 1.08;

            totalPriceEditText.setText(String.format("%.02f", totalPrice));

        }
    });

}
```

}

Thank you so much!!

Comment: So it the problem that you can not run a program on Andriod?

Comment: what wont run.. what is the error..

Comment: Do you get any error in logcat?

Comment: Please put your error log.

Comment: I am required to use NetBean and NetBean did not give me any error sign... I don't know what is going wrong everytime when I tried to run it ran but the emulator showed "Tax Calculator has to stop"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem can be in these lines:

```
tagPriceEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tagPriceEditText);
tagPriceEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.totalPriceEditText); //your reassigned tagPriceEditText  here
```

Change to

```
    tagPriceEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tagPriceEditText);
    totalPriceEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.totalPriceEditText);
```

Comment: @zzhao33 : Edited my answer, please check

Answer (score 0):

You didn't posted the logcat, I think you have to initialize tagPrice. Try adding

```
double tagPrice=0.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your activity (TaxCalculator) in manifest. Did you?

Answer (score 0):

I am not very clear to your question.
If you need your correct required value then, I think you are not putting correct calculation for this ..

Try :

```
double totalPrice = tagPrice * .08 + tagPrice;
```

Comment: Isn't tagPrice*1.08 the same as tagPrice*0.08 + tagPrice?!

Answer (score 0):

u might getting an error for the line

```
tagPriceEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.totalPriceEditText);
```

change to

```
totalPriceEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.totalPriceEditText);
```

and u have declared **EditText text** but never used it

in ur xml file add this line for both edittext

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

Comment: I put android:inputType="number" in my xml file. Are they the same?